# How to shrink website 25%

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was tasked with having to shrink a website by 25%. Meaning, all images and fonts/elements need to be reduced by 25% size.

My first solution was jQuery, by doing the following:

```
-webkit-transform: scale(.75);
```

However, this caused issues because a lot of this site was built in images. For instance, the header now doesn't expand the entire screen, because it is an image with a fixed size.  The footer also has a problem, it now has a huge margin bottom (prolly a good 500px) that I can't seem to remove.

Any other solutions you guys can think of?

So far I'm either going to:

A) Continue with my jQuery method and try to fix the issues mentioned above

B) Literally go through and physically shrink everything by 25% and remove the jQuery.

Comment: How about CSS `zoom: 0.75;` on the body? :)

Comment: @AKX `zoom: 0.75;` is a shorthand for `transform: scale(.75);`, which the OP has already explicitly described in their question.

Comment: Just to clarify, `-webkit-transform: scale(.75);` isn't jQuery — it's CSS.

Comment: Yeah sorry that is CSS. However, @AKX your solution worked great. Had completely different effect then the -webkit. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, that is unexpected! Had no idea the implementation changed when applied on a page-wide level…

Comment: @user1696090 -- made that comment an answer, so if you can accept it if it worked for you... :)

Answer (score 7):

`Literally go through and physically shrink everything by 25% and remove the jQuery.`

Do this. Using jQuery to do this is unprofessional and will make a bad quality website, as well as setting you up for errors in the future. It won't take long

Comment: -1 "_Using jQuery to do this…_": A close reader would have noticed there was no jQuery code in the OP's question; "_Do this_": not a technical solution to the problem; "_…this is unprofessional…_": technically irrelevant to the question, and a vague matter of opinion. There is nothing 'unprofessional' about using jQuery.

Comment: @Barney He specifically stated the above fix (B), or a jQuery fix(A), I answered the question with B. `Do this` isn't code, but the changes that B required IS a technical solution. As for unprofessional-ism, I'm pretty sure that is something all developers strive for, or else we would still be using tables if they got the job done. I said using jQuery for THIS fix would be unprofessional, not jQuery in general. I think you need to read more carefully and not downvote an answer just because you answered the same question.

Comment: "_using jQuery for THIS fix would be unprofessional_" isn't that still a vague and subjective matter of opinion? "_Literally go through and physically shrink everything by 25%_" what is the technical solution for this?

Comment: @Barney I don't know what your problem is? The OP wasn't asking for me to provide him with a technical solution (aka code), and it would be ridiculous to think otherwise. He was asking for the most appropriate method, which I stated.

Answer (score 1):

*(promoting as an answer from the comment on the OP)*

How about CSS `zoom: 0.75;` on the body? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `em`-based measurements, you can achieve this with the following code:

```
html {
  font-size: 75%;
}
```

However, elements that *don't* have explicit dimensions, or dimensions set in absolute units, won't be affected — you'll need to specify those properties.

For images, you'll need to know what their original dimensions are, and calculate and specify the desired dimensions yourself.

Comment: No, I was suggesting it as a solution to the problem. Using `em`s to size websites is [recommended](http://alistapart.com/article/fluidgrids) as [good](http://css-tricks.com/why-ems/) [practice](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/css2em.htm) by leading figures in web design. I don't understand why it's 'very unlikely' that the OP would use them. Besides, that's pure conjecture — not a mis-reading or technical error on my part.